# C++ IDE with Best Hints, autocomplete or autofill

Tags: c++, xcode, windows, autocomplete, ide

I'm moving from MAC/XCode C++ developing to Windows platform (please stop asking why?)

I have been programing in XCode for a while and I noticed that it has an amazing hints and autocomplete assistant.

Now in Windows... I  feel I'm back to the 80s, I already tried NetBeans, Visual Studio 2012, Dev++, Eclipse... all garbage, to say the least.

They can't even hint or autofill a local var or a local class method, I need to type again every single word, I miss so much real time parsing in XCode.. sniff.

Any "hint"? Or pluging that I may check out?

Comment: Looks like a good question to ask on programmers.stackexchange ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm comfortable with QtCreator, but it gives the best developing Qt specific code.

To be true, I worked a lot in Visual Studio, til 2010, and autocompletion etc worked, a bit slowly. If you consider it garbage, maybe you will dislike QtCreator as well.

Comment: In my opinion the autocompletion works much better in QtCreator than in Visual Studio, so I think your answer is helpful even if the OP already tried Visual Studio

Comment: I typed: int MyVar; next line I go MyV and I can stay there 1min VSudio does nothing... XCode almost instantly hitns "MyVar" ... something like that is what I looking for... does VS2012 do that for you?

Comment: Sorry, I switched to Linux more than 2 years ago, I have no more VS available...But QtCreator works well in Windows, too. Never tried on IOS, should work as well...

Answer (score 2):

I also prefer QtCreator to Visual Studio, but if you add the [Wholetomato Visual Assist](http://www.wholetomato.com/) plugin to Visual Studio then it becomes much better.

Comment: I see there's many versions of QT, for a free one which would you suggest?

Comment: @Barbara1492 http://qt.digia.com/Product/Developer-Tools/ You can download QtCreator as a standalone product or together with the whole Qt SDK (if you want to develop Qt based applications). As a stand alone product it can use the Visual Studio compiler or Mingw. All the versions are free.

Comment: @ Paolo Brandoli I just want to run C++ code, I did download QT standalone but now I can't compile or run my Apps...

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to check more the **Refactoring** capabilities of Eclipse, Netbeans and Visual Studio, or you can edit **Templates** of new types .

Comment: Could you be more specific please??? THX!

Comment: Here is a video demonstrating some refactoring options of Netbeans : http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xHZbOBztQ2k